# Gravity affects neutrons

Tags: particle-physics, newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, neutrons

A long time ago I asked whether gravity affected subatomic particles. An experimental physicist kindly explained that it's known to affect neutrons. Get a neutron source, and send a beam of neutrons horizontally. The slower neutrons fall farther in a given distance.

That doesn't tell us whether gravity affects charged particles, but it's plausible it would and their charges make the effect of gravity so small that it's hard to detect.

Does gravity affect all neutrons equally?

Suppose there's some neutron quality that results in neutrons that are not affected by gravity, or affected less. Then slow neutrons that ARE affected by gravity would fall, and the lower neutrons would be enriched for them.

Say for example that neutrons that spin on one axis are affected by gravity, and neutrons that spin pn another axis are not. Then if you start with neutrons spinning in all directions, they would be smeared out according to their spins. And it would work the same with anything that changed gravity's effect.

Also, if you could suddenly cut off the source of neutrons, then if they are all affected equally, the last slow neutrons would arrive later, after all the fast neutrons are gone and they would all be low. If there are slow neutrons that do not fall, then the late neutrons would be spread out.

Have these experiments been done? Is it known whether all neutrons are equally affected by gravity?

Comment: The point of this experiment is that neutrons with higher speeds accumulates bigger relativistic energy as per $E= \sqrt {(pc)^{2}+\left(m_{0}c^{2}\right)^{2}}$. And so neutrons with greater speed are attracted by greater gravitational force as per $F=GMmr^{-2}$ and due to that they fall faster to gravitational source, compared to slower neutrons.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was the other way around, which seemed reasonable. At nonrelativistic speeds, slow neutrons would have longer for gravity to act on them before they reach a detector.

Either way, there might be something about some of them that results in them being affected differently, and that could be detected if it happens to enough of them to affect the statistics.

Comment: If detector measures vertical, i.e. gravity-based displacement of neutrons, then this should not depend directly on horizontal kinetic energy of neutron, i.e. at nonrelativistic speeds slow and faster neutrons falls at the same rate _vertically_. However as soon as you'll introduce neutrons with relativistic horizontal speeds, it increases relativistic mass of neutrons considerably, thus they should be attracted by gravity more and fall-down at faster rates.

Comment: It's established that all known particles with mass are affected by gravity.  See, e.g.,  https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=64066#:~:text=Gravity%20acts%20between%20quarks%20%5B6,slow%20moving%20or%20stationary%20objects.

Comment: Same about particles with no rest mass, i.e. that's why we have gravitational lensing, due to which photons bends from a linear usual course spatially. Also if photons would not be affected by gravity, then there would be no such thing as [Photon_sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere),- i.e. photons circling black hole.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas At nonrelativistic speeds, slow and fast neutrons will fall at the same rate per unit time. But if a detector is present at a fixed distance from the source, fast neutrons will reach the detector sooner, so they won't have as long to fall.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It looks like your link shows theoretical reason why all particles with mass should be affected by gravity. If in practice different kinds of neutrons are affected differently, it might be possible to detect that. I'm asking whether that's been tested.

Comment: @JThomas That's why experimental set-up must be constructed so that detector could extrapolate _vertical fall rates_ per unit time, no matter at what speed neutron hits the target. Given that more massive particles (with greater rest or relativistic energy) must fall vertically at greater rates per unit time, due to greater Earth traction (Newton universal gravity law).

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Do I understand correctly what you're saying? Are you saying that Newton said that things with greater mass fall faster? Didn't Galileo settle that question?

Comment: @JThomas Nope, certainly not. Maybe I was tired or something. Sure, in vacuum case all things fall at the same acceleration as per equation $ mg = GMmr^{-2} $. So this free-fall rate $g$ could be re-validated with neutron source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138220/discussion-between-j-thomas-and-agnius-vasiliauskas).

Answer (score 3):

> Have these experiments been done?

[Here is an experiment](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v11/s34),

> Newton’s law of universal gravitation predicts that the gravitational force between two objects is proportional to the objects’ masses and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them. *The law, which applies to weakly interacting objects traveling at speeds much slower than that of light, has survived test after test.* However, some quantum gravity theories anticipate that the law might break down at small distances

italics mine for stressing the point.

they

> have checked Newton’s law on subnanometer scales. So far, the team has found no deviations from Newtonian predictions.

> Is it known whether all neutrons are equally affected by gravity?

Neutrons, in mainstream physics which is discussed on this site, are quantum mechanical entities, and in quantum mechanics one neutron is indistinguishable from another, i.e. the neutrons in the pulsed neutron beam for the experiment linked above are considered to have the same quantum numbers and energy/momentum obeying the same boundary conditions. Deviations from this, i.e width of momentum distribution etc will enter into the error given by the experiment.

> The team is currently upgrading the setup to reduce sources of noise and envisions achieving order-of-magnitude sensitivity improvements in the near future.

Comment: Thank you! That's very much the sort of thing I was hoping for! "neutrons in the pulsed neutron beam for the experiment linked above are considered to have the same quantum numbers and energy/momentum obeying the same boundary conditions. Deviations from this, i.e width of momentum distribution etc will enter into the error given by the experiment." Yes, assume there is no difference, with a statistical prediction of results. I presume that a bimodal distribution when a unimodal distribution is predicted, might show there are two kinds of neutrons which can be separated. If that is true.